# jquery/javascript maintain linebreak when copying text

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Suppose I have

```
<input type="hidden" id="in1">

...

<p id="editable_p"></p>

<script> 
$('#some_button').click( function() {
  $('#in1').val($('#editable_p').text());
});
</script>
```

Clearly, my intention is to set the value of the hidden field to be the content of the <p> tag. This works, however it does not maintain line breaks, which is important for me. Is there a basic library function that will copy the value of the editable paragraph that maintains the linebreaks, or is there some kind of extended hack that must be performed to get this to work as I intend?

Thanks much in advance.

Comment: is the editable text stored as HTML ? ie what makes the line break ? <br/> ? if so try using `.html()` instead of `text()`

Comment: I think the <input> itself removes the line breaks, not JavaScript. Did you try to replace the input with a <textarea> tag, and hide that textarea through css style (style="display: none") ?

Comment: I've tried that, but it still doesn't maintain linebreaks copying into the textarea.

Comment: @ManseUK - This does appear to work, however I was a bit suprised to find that it would wrap the newline in a '<div><br></div><div> new-line-of-text.. </div>'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find there are a number of text nodes in your #editable_p.p and calling text() as per a lot of XML type environments, will just concatenate the strings from the text nodes found in the descendant tree, potentially losing structure. This operation can do weird stuff to line breaks and other whitespace.

To avoid this, iterate over the actual text nodes, and concatenate the strings yourself, adding \n end of lines as necessary. Assuming you have succeeded in this and have the string with line breaks, I think talereader could be correct that a textarea or similar may be needed to represent the resulting string, and submit it faithfully to a server.

Selecting text nodes with JQuery is already outlined in 
[How do I select text nodes with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298750/how-do-i-select-text-nodes-with-jquery)